# Excel vba import several sheets to single sheet and keeping the formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a totally newbee on vba.
I have managed to import several sheets from other workbooks to one single sheet.
But I would like to keep the formatting and also keep the color of the cells being imported.
This is my code sofar:

```
Public strFileName As String
Public currentWB As Workbook
Public dataWB As Workbook
Public strCopyRange As String

Sub delData() 'Clears MasterData except 1st line
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
    Case Is = "List", "Sheet1"
        ' Do Nothing
    Case Else
        ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents


    End Select
Next ws
End Sub

Sub GetData()
Dim strWhereToCopy As String, strStartCellColName As String
Dim strListSheet As String

strListSheet = "List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("B2").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Exit Sub


ErrH:
    MsgBox "It seems some file was missing. The data copy operation is not complete."
Exit Sub


End Sub

Public Function LastRowInOneColumn(col)
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    LastRowInOneColumn = lastRow
End Function
```

My function GetData() doesnt overwrite existing data - so I made a workaround and created function delData(). How do I make the function GetData to overwrite existing data?
And I would like to keep the formatting and color from the sheets I import from. This should also overwrite old data/colors.

I really hope this makes sense to someone :o)
Any advise is most apreciated
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

instead of `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone`

Comment: It seems to work if I keep both lines instead of replacing the old line with the new. Do you know how I can hide cells with a specific color? Like Sort and Filtre - but I would like to be able to hide the cells with a specific color

Comment: Never mind the question about hiding celss with specific color. I have done this with Sort and filter. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it :o)